# Overlapping routes in react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've got number of nested routes and would want them to be displayed one at time.

The top route is, let's say, '/sports'

```
<>
  <Route exact path={`${match.path}/favs`} component={LiveFavs} />
  <Route exact path={`${match.path}/:sportId`} render={props => <Live {...props.match.params} />} />
  <Route exact path={`${match.path}/:sportId/:eventId`} render={props => <LiveEvent {...props.match.params} />} />
</>
```

Navigating to `/sports/favs` should display first route ONLY, but currently it's mixed with route no. 2 (`:sportId`)

Comment: you missed exact attribute for the first route

Comment: Yeah, it's not doing anything in my case really

Comment: Just wrote you a solution, let me know if that helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import the `Switch` component from `react-router-dom` and wrap it around your Routes. Essentially, it goes through your routes and renders only the first route who's path is satisfied by the URL being navigated to.

Try this:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path={`${match.path}/favs`} component={LiveFavs} />
  <Route exact path={`${match.path}/:sportId`} render={props => <Live {...props.match.params} />} />
  <Route exact path={`${match.path}/:sportId/:eventId`} render={props => <LiveEvent {...props.match.params} />} />
</Switch>
```